# Wagtail: render a page programmatically in a Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-class-based-views, wagtail

I've got a Wagtail setting where a user can select a page to render, and if it is not set, it returns a listing page using `ListView` of recent posts. Here is the setting:

```
@register_setting
class PeregrineSettings(BaseSetting):
    """
    Settings for the user to customize their Peregrine blog.
    """
    landing_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text='The page to display at the root. If blank, displays the latest posts.'
    )
```

The setting works. When I try to use it in the `ListView`, I'm attempting to pass the `url_path` to Wagtail's `serve` method, but it doesn't render the page view; I get a 404. Here's the code of the `ListView`:

```
class PostsListView(ListView):
    """
    Paginated view of blog posts.
    """
    model = SitePost
    template_name = 'peregrine/site_post_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['-post_date']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        peregrine_settings = PeregrineSettings.for_site(request.site)
        if peregrine_settings.landing_page is None:
            # Render list of recent posts
            response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return response
        else:
            # Render landing page
            return serve(request, peregrine_settings.landing_page.url_path)
```

It feels like I'm missing a way to just pass the `Page` instance stored in `peregrine_settings.landing_page` to a method to render. Can anyone shed some light on the internals at work here? Thank you!

Comment: So I got it working - silly mistake. I replaced `return serve(request, peregrine_settings.landing_page.url_path)` with `return serve(request, peregrine_settings.landing_page.url)`. But my question remains: is there a better way to do this with the `Page` instance or is using the `Page.url` the way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it the `serve` function you're calling here is the view defined in `wagtail.core.views`? This view doesn't do much by itself - it calls `route()` on the site root page to locate the correct page, then calls that page's `serve()` method (passing the request object) to do the actual page rendering. It looks like this latter `serve()` method is what you need:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    peregrine_settings = PeregrineSettings.for_site(request.site)
    if peregrine_settings.landing_page is None:
        # ...
    else:
        # Render landing page
        return peregrine_settings.landing_page.serve(request)
```

Some further documentation about the `route` and `serve` methods can be found here:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/theory.html#anatomy-of-a-wagtail-request
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method